# create trigger in postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am migrating to it from MySQL.Trying to creating Trigger in that.But can't done with it.

This is my MySQL Query.

```
  delimiter $$
  create trigger delVPNProfile before delete on VPN_Profile_List for each row begin update userinfo set Profile_ID='-1' where Profile_ID=old.Profile_ID; end;$$
  delimiter ;
```

My PostgreSQL Query is like this.

```
  $ CREATE FUNCTION make_default_privileges() returns trigger as $$
  begin
  update userinfo set Profile_ID='-1' where Profile_ID=old.Profile_ID;
  end;
  $$ language plpgsql;
  create trigger delVPNProfile before delete on VPN_Profile_List for each row begin EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_default_privileges();
```

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your PostgreSQL trigger? Syntax errors? Doesn't do what you expect it to? Something else?

Comment: What is the error message shown? Please provide some more details.

Comment: One thing I noticed, there is no need to include "begin" in trigger creation syntax. It could be just written as,  "..for each row EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_default_privileges();".

Comment: @muistooshort It doesn't show any error messages.But when I check for crated triggers it doesn't shows any.

Comment: @Vijay same doesn't work.I am checking the available triggers with select * from pg_trigger; is it right?

Comment: I don't have postgres installed in my machine right now to help you out. There is an option to create triggers from pgadmin. Try that to make sure if the problem is in the query or not.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION make_default_privileges() RETURNS trigger AS      $make_default_privileges$
old_id          integer;
BEGIN
old_id=OLD.Profile_ID;
update userinfo set Profile_ID='-1' where Profile_ID=old_id;
RETURN OLD;
END;
   $make_default_privileges$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delVPNProfile before delete on VPN_Profile_List
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_default_privileges();
```